# Finding stations for Rhythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

I can Google for stations I'd like to listen to, but I can't find the correct URL to put into Rhythmbox for them to work.

Do I need to find stations that offer a specific kind of protocol?

i.e. "PLS" (playlist?) Where are some top-notch places to find stations?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**[Shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com)**

Shoutcast is a massive selection of individual radio stations (over 700 pages). There are so many stations that it is intimidating to even find one.

How to add Radio Stations to Rhythmbox?

- Vist [Shoutcast](http://www.shoutcast.com), find your favorite radio station, right click on it and select `Save Link As`, Save it in your music library.

[image]

- Right click on .pls file you just downloaded and select `Open with Rhythmbox`.
- Alternatively, instead of saving the .pls file just copy the link location, in Rhythmbox select `Radios` in side bar and click on add, enter the link there and save it.

  [image]
- 3rd option is to open the `.pls` file in Gedit and copy the address from there and add it to Rhythmbox.

  [image]

**Alternative:**

Or just install [Guayadeque](http://guayadeque.org/forums/index.php?p=/). Listen and browse the complete Shoutcast collection (Over 5,700 stations) and many other radio stations right from your desktop. It's available in Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Comment: This is a super answer. Option 1 failed for me with a Rhythmbox error (error in either Rhythmbox or Gstreamer). Option 2 worked a treat - and is easier.

Comment: Awesome! Still valid for 2016. On Linux Mint Serena.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to get the url of a radio stream I check the source code of the radio player.
E.g [this dutch radio station](http://radioplayer.omroep.nl/3fm-default/)

Get the source code of the page and  go to line 147, you will see this

```
{ codec: 'asx', url: 'http://livestreams.omroep.nl/npo/3fm-bb', stream: true }
```

Add the url  to rhytmbox and voila.

Comment: have you managed to get a .pls playing in rythmbox?  i too have tried for a specific station and can't?  you still got a +1

Answer (score 4):

http://listenlive.eu has a good database with easy access to the playlist files that Rhythmbox can make use of.

Comment: this website is dead

Answer (score 3):

Yes a good answer from Basharat Sial.

It is too bad RhythmBox still cannot open downloaded `.pls` files by just clicking them. It was reported as a bug on 2006-10-04 ([LP bug #62430](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/62430)), and still nobody had this fixed. Anyway if you want RhythmBox to run a specific `.pls` file you can open your terminal and run this:

```
rhythmbox-client --play-uri=[PATH HERE]
```

This solution was given under the discussion of the bug, but it is a long discussion and it can be difficult to spot it. It does not solve the bug, but it is a way to get around it. I know this info here is for the coding-oriented user, but now you know.

Comment: Your answer would be highly improved if you provide the link to that bug.